# Change web root directory - problem with anchor links

Tags: .htaccess, web, root

I tried edit web root directory via `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newweb/
RewriteRule (.*) /newweb/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

and in `index.html` code change `CSS`, `JS` links via base tag

```
<base href="http://example.com/newweb/">
```

but anchror links not redirect to `example.com/#tag` but to `example.com/newweb#tag`

I need the first option to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but anchror links not redirect to `example.com/#tag` but to `example.com/newweb#tag`

Yes, using a `base` element (to correct relative URLs) is not without its caveats. An in-page anchor such as `#tag` is a "relative URL", so this is now relative to the `base` URL.

The only way to resolve this is to fully qualify your in-page links, with a root-relative (or absolute) URL to the current page/URL. (Which may defeat the point of using the `base` tag in the first place as a workaround for your *other* relative URLs.) Or don't use relative URLs to your resources / other pages in the first place.

See my answer to [a similar question on the Pro Webmasters stack](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css) for more detail:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243

---

**UPDATE:** Having had a look at your website, which is essentially a one-page website that relies on fragment identifiers (ie. `#tag`) for all in-page links then you should change all *relative* URLs to your resources (CSS, JS and images) to be root-relative (starting with a slash) and remove the `base` element.

By "root-relative", it should be root-relative to your *expected* client-side root, not the actual filesystem root.

For example, the following relative URL in your HTML source:

```
vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Should be changed to a root-relative URL (not a filesystem path):

```
/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Note that this does not include the `/newweb` filesystem subdirectory.

The directives in `.htaccess` then *internally rewrite* the URL to `/newweb/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css` (the underlying filesystem path). The `/newweb` subdirectory is then entirely hidden from the client.

By using the `base` tag in your HTML you are also exposing the `/newweb` subdirectory to the client (and search engines) and potentially creating duplicate content, since your site is available at both `example.com/` and `example.com/newweb/`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newweb/
> RewriteRule (.*) /newweb/ [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> ```

However, these directives are not correct. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? The last `RewriteCond` directive is invalid on its own at the end. And the preceding `RewriteRule` rewrites *everyithing* to the directory root (which may explain why you resorted to using relative URLs in your HTML source?)

To rewrite everything to the corresponding URL in the `/newweb` subdirectory then you would need something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite enverything to the /newweb subdirectory
RewriteRule !^newweb/ /newweb%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This assumes that your page only references resources that are contained within the `/newweb` subdirectory and not elsewhere on the filesystem. If you are then you will also need a filesystem check.

However, by itself, this doesn't resolve the issue of `example.com/newweb/` still being accessible (although this is less important now that the URL-path is not exposed). By this can be resolved with an external redirect from `/newweb` back to the document root (but we need to be careful of a redirect loop, given the rewrite in the opposite direction).

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If /newweb is requested directly then redirect to remove it
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^newweb/?(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Rewrite enverything to the /newweb subdirectory
RewriteRule !^newweb/ /newweb%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Change the 302 (temporary) rediredct to 301 (permanent) only when you have confirmed it is working OK.

Comment: Since you have a "one-page" website and rely heavily on in-page links for your navigation, you should instead change all your resource URLs to be root-relative and remove the `base` element. Your `.htaccess` file is also not correct. I've updated my answer.